# Play DVD in VideoLan DotNet

Tags: c#, wpf, video-encoding, libvlc

We're using [VideoLan DotNet for WPF](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/) to build a video player. I play files using:

```
mediaPlayer.Play(filePath);
```

But I can't figure out how to play a DVD and show its menu (with the ability to navigate the menu ...). Here is what I've tried so far:

```
mediaPlayer.Play(@"F:\");
mediaPlayer.Play(@"F:\VIDEO_TS");
mediaPlayer.Play("dvd:///F:/");
```

And if I directly play VTS_01_0.VOB the menu is not interactive.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this

```
mediaPlayer.Media = new LocationMedia("dvd:///D:");    
mediaPlayer.Play();
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of `LocationMedia`. Is there any documentation about these?  It's showing the menu, but I can't interact with it. It seems the control is transparent. How can I direct Mouse and Keyboard input to the control?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any dvd player to test this. But I think this is some option issue. You can find your answer at vlc wiki 
[link](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help)
And downloading source code and investigate from good idea too
[link](https://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Vlc.DotNet/Vlc.DotNet.Core/Medias/PathMedia.cs)

Comment: @OzanYurtseven Thanks for the documentation link, it's very helpful. Unfortunately my problem isn't solved. I think it has something to do with it being a WPF wrapper. (and not fully compatible with WPF) I've also started a discussion on the project site: https://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/discussions/549954 But no answers so far.